# Automatically include git subtree in pushes and pulls

Tags: git, github, version-control

Currently, I'm working with two repos - `frontend` and `backend` that need to share a couple of files. I have these files in a third repo called `shared`, with all of these repos stored on GitHub.

I have been looking into using git subtrees to share `shared` between the two repos. Currently, if I change a file in e.g. `frontend/shared` locally, I have to

1. push the changes to *both* the `frontend` and `shared` repos
2. make sure to directly pull these changes to `backend` using `git subtree pull` to sync the files
3. make sure to constantly check if there are changes in `shared` because executing `git status` in `frontend` or `backend` does not show these changes

This whole process seems quite tedious and error-prone, so **I'm wondering if there is a way to automatically include the `shared` subtree in git pulls and pushes?**

If it helps, I know that this will be the only subtree used in the project.

---

Alternatively, is there a way to "save" the `shared` GitHub URL (and `main` branch) so at the very least I don't have to copy and paste it each time I run

```
git subtree push --prefix=shared SHARED-GITHUB-URL main
```

---

I'm not sure what the best way to do this is / haven't update git's config before, so any advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: It's tough to do with `git push`, and `git pull` is the wrong tool, but it's easy to add a second *remote* to any Git repository and use `git remote update` (or `git fetch --all`, which does the same thing, but `git remote` has more/better controls; see [the `git remote` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote)). After a `git remote update` you can inspect the local copies of commits in `origin/<branch>` *and* `shared/<branch>` (assuming you've named the second remote `shared` here).

Comment: This is not a *lot* of help, but it might make the hump a bit easier. Subtree in general is poorly maintained: someone needs to adopt it and become the `git subtree` maintainer for the Git project.

Comment: @torek Thank you for that advice! It seems like the problem is my stupidity and lack of using the project's API as an abstraction tool, so I think I will reframe the project in a smarter way. If we do end up needing to share files anyway, though, I will definitely try this out! Thanks again